# Why is my jar file opening NetBeans instead of executing?

Tags: java

I have created the jar file of my java Netbeans project using the clean and build option.

It builds successfully but when I click on the jar file it does not execute. Instead it opens NetBeans.

It does not give any error.

Comment: Is it a console program or a GUI? and did you add the JOptionPane to show the errors?

Comment: Use `java -jar thejar.jar`, in your command line window.

Comment: i have tried this  java -jar thejar.jar in command line but it shows the error that thejar is not accessible

Comment: What is the exact and complete error you get? thejar.jar must of course be the actual path to the actual jar file. Not literally thejar.jar.

Comment: @JB NIizet when i click the jar file that is in dist folder of the project it just opens the Net beans IDE but not run the project standalone.

Comment: Then you have a configuration issue of your OS. Youu probably told it to open jar files with NetBeans instead of executing them.

Comment: how to correct it..

Comment: What OS are you using?